Baskervaldx doesn’t allow certain glyphs
This MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx}


\begin{document}
\ss{} dreißig fließen „Test“ "Test" ‚Test‘ »Test« ›Test‹

12345

\end{document}

yields this:

Employing \ss{} shows that »ß« can be accessed without any trouble. The different quotation glyphs are also not employed properly. Baskervaldx is available as OpenType or TrueType, according to the LaTeX Font Catalogue. What can I do to write the glyphs without using extra commands?

Baskervaldx.sty is designed for 8-bit engines and should not be used with Unicode engines. However, the package provides baskervaldx.fontspec, which you can use, if you wish, with Unicode engines.
For example, the following will load the  .fontspec configuration provided by baskervaldx:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% \usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx}
\setmainfont{baskervaldx}[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]


\begin{document}
\ss{} dreißig fließen „Test“ "Test" ‚Test‘ »Test« ›Test‹

12345

\end{document}


+1. \setmainfont{Baskervaldx} (note the uppercase letter "B") works too. :-)

@Mico I thought so, too, but I just checked and it does not work in the same way. That is, it doesn't find the .fontspec file if you don't get the case correct.

Hmmm, I'm using LuaLaTeX. Are you using XeLaTeX?

@Mico no I only tried with LuaTeX. note that the output is OK anyway, but it only uses the .fontspec file if the case matches. are you using a case insensitive filesystem?

I use MacTeX2024 on a MacOS 15.1.1 system.

@Mico is that case insensitive? I heard mac was switching, but I don't know what 15.1.1 means or whether you are using the default file system anyway. just that seems the most likely cause for a difference. note that you may have a mix of file systems, some case sensitive and some not. one partition of my disk is, in fact, case insensitive. but the rest of it is case sensitive.

Sorry for being needlessly obtuse -- version 15.1.1 is the most recent version of MacOS. I just performed the following, admittedly non-exhaustive, test: From my home directory I can switch to the "documents" subdirectory by typing cd documents, cd Documents, or even cd DOCUMENTS, and each time I get to the same place. In short, this version of MacOS would indeed appear to be case-insensitive. :-)

@Mico I must be wrong then about them changing the default. so, yes, maybe that's why.
